# React : why state change when try to change it in immutable way , before calling the setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I try to change state immutable way in `React`, it is changing the state before I call `setstate`, which confused me for 3 days now.

This is the method I call in the `onClick` event:

```
share = (indexFolder) => {
    console.log(this.state.folderInfo);
    const updateFolderInfo = [...this.state.folderInfo];
    updateFolderInfo[indexFolder].isProcessing = false; 

    //state**is already changed**strong text** when console **
    console.log(this.state.folderInfo);

    this.setState({
            folderInfo : updateFolderInfo,
    })
    // the setState call do not take effect here 
}
```

This is where the method is executed:

```
<Folder key={folder._id}
        sharing={this.state.folderIsProcessing}
        folder={folder} 
        delete={() => this.delete(index)}
        share={() => this.share(index)} />
//I'm passing share function as props in here ^ , and use it on 
//click event in the Folder component .
```

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: Should this line `updateFolderInfo[indexFolder].isProcessing = false;` be `this.state.indexFolder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that by doing `const updateFolderInfo = [...this.state.folderInfo];` you are effectively making a **shallow** copy of `folderInfo`.

What that means is that, if you modify any item inside `updateFolderInfo` that is an object or an array, you will also be modifying the same object/array inside the original `folderInfo` array.

Assuming `folderInfo` has only JSON inside, here's a potential solution using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to create a deep copy:

```
share = indexFolder => {
  const updatedFolderInfo = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.folderInfo));
  updatedFolderInfo[indexFolder].isProcessing = false; 

  this.setState({ folderInfo : updatedFolderInfo });
}
```

Here's a tiny example of show you what you are currently doing in a simplified way:

```
array1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
array2 = [...array1]

array2[0].id = 100

array2
// [{id: 100}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]

array1
// [{id: 100}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
```

*You can find more info on shallow vs deep cloning [here](https://smoothprogramming.com/javascript/explanation-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy-js/).*

Comment: Hi . thank's for answering .  you solved mi problem thank's a lot. before i post this deep copy comme to my head , but in this way : what i tried to do is                          [...{...this.state.folderInfo}]   // but it does not do what expected at all .     thank's again

Comment: Hey there. No problem! I'm glad this has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are already binding the function to the scope above. Try changing it like this.

```
share = (indexFolder) => {
      console.log(this.state.folderInfo);
      const updateFolderInfo = [...this.state.folderInfo];
      updateFolderInfo[indexFolder].isProcessing = false; 
      //state**is already changed**strong text** when console **
       console.log(this.state.folderInfo);
      this.setState({
            folderInfo : updateFolderInfo,
      })
      // the setState call do not take effect here 
    }

<Folder  key={folder._id}
                                sharing={this.state.folderIsProcessing}
                                folder={folder} 
                                delete={this.delete(index)}
                                share={this.share(index)}
        />
```

Comment: hi , thank's for answering , but if we do as you say,  this.share(index) will be executed onces the component will be mounted , so function array is an obligation her .    @NMarcora has the right solution . thank's again

Answer (score 0):

Too few information provided, but try to use setState in other way:

```
share = (indexFolder) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
        const updateFolderInfo = [...prevState.folderInfo];
        updateFolderInfo[indexFolder].isProcessing = false; 
        return { 
            folderInfo : updateFolderInfo
        }
  }) 
}
```

About async nature of setState: https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

Comment: hi , sorry if that was not clear enough , i'll correct this in the my futur post issu . #NMarcora has the right answer . thank's a lot